# Install Headers on Kali

Tags: kali-linux

```
apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.9.0-kali3-amd64
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.9.0-kali3-amd64'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.9.0-kali3-amd64'
```

Answer (score 4):

Kali only keeps a limited set of kernels, and you can only install headers for kernels which are still available in the pool. The current kernel (as of March 1, 2018) is [`4.14.0-kali3`](http://pkg.kali.org/pkg/linux), older versions are no longer available.

The fix is the same for any kernel version on Kali. You need to update your indexes:

```
sudo apt update
```

then upgrade, which should install the new kernel:

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

then reboot to use the new kernel and try again:

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get install linux-headers-4.9.0-kali3-amd64
```

The last command may fail if your system is not fully updated. I used this command and it was successful:

```
apt-get install linux-headers-amd64
```